# HOW TO: Send mail with PHPMailer class or PHPMailerAutoload?

Tags: php, phpmailer

**first**:  Im traying to send a simple email without attachment with PHPMailer class 
**second**: The code i have is not working with 
require('../libs/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php'); //here is throwing me a fatal error

[image]

**third**:  I already tried with the PHPMailerAutoload class 
      **require('../libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');** // here it doesnt throw any error, but is not sending me anything

```
<?php
require('../libs/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

echo $_POST['InputName'];
echo $_POST['InputEmail'];
echo $_POST['InputMessage'];

if(!isset($_POST['InputName']) || 
    !isset($_POST['InputEmail']) || 
    !isset($_POST['InputMessage'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}

$inputName = $_POST['InputName'];  
$inputEmail = $_POST['InputEmail'];  
$inputMessage = $_POST['InputMessage']; 
$error_message = "";

$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'mail.domain.com.mx';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->Username   = 'contact@domain.com.mx';
$mail->Password   = 'mypassword';

$mail->SetFrom($inputEmail, 'something here');
// $mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@mycomp.com','no-reply');
$mail->Subject    = 'CONTACT '.$inputEmail;
$mail->MsgHTML($inputMessage);

$mail->AddAddress('contact@domain.com.mx', 'contact');
$mail->AddAddress('other@domain.com.mx', 'other'); /* ... */

// $mail->AddAttachment($fileName);
$mail->send();
```

?>

Comment: are you running localhost?.. if thats the case. activate the smtp. you can configure a fake mailer

Comment: +joshua Belarmino. Thanks for the answer but minutes ago i could fix the issue. My issue it was in the smtp credentials. I was confused about TLS ans SSL and PORT. Even i was running in localhost i didnt have to configure anything. rare Regards

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example - start with the code examples provided with PHPMailer, and make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: @Synchro PhpMailer is not an obsolete library And the example is a tipical way to send a simple mail

Comment: I know it's not obsolete - I'm the maintainer! *Your example code* is obsolete - use the examples provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not even attempt to detect failures. You don't enable exceptions:

```
$mail=new PHPMailer();
```

... and you don't verify the result:

```
$mail->send();
```

I suggest you enable exceptions:

```
$mail=new PHPMailer(true);
```

... or at least verify if message was accepted by the server:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
   // Log to file and warn user
}
```

Additionally, PHPMailer was several debug features you should try. Please check the `SMTPDebug` and `Debugoutput` properties.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro Gonzalez. The last validatuon i already wrote it. The flag in true i will try it. Thanks for the debug suggestions Im completely new in Php. Regards!